# The existence of solution of the ODE $\dot{x}(t) = F(x(t),t)$ with discontinuous $F$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the non-autonomous O.D.E

$\dot{x}(t) = \int h(x(t),y)\mu(t,dy)=F(x(t),t)$

where $\mu(t,dy) = \delta_{y_n}(dy)$ when $t \in [t_n,t_{n+1})$

where $y_n$ and $t_n$ are given sequences s.t. $y_n$ lies in a complete separable metric space $U$ and $t_n$ diverges but $t_{n+1} - t_n$ converges to zero. $\delta$ being the Dirac measure. $h$ is jointly continuous and uniformly Lipschitz in first component w.r.t the second.

Now a book claims that this O.D.E has a solution. But $F$ is discontinuous in the second component at the points $t_n$. So, Picard's theorem does not apply. So, does this O.D.E has a solution ? I don't see.

Comment: @anorton: I thought it is obvious. Anyways, I have written it more clearly.

Comment: Well, the integral is actually just $h(x(t),y_n)$ whenever $t \in [t_n,t_{n+1})$. So on each finite time interval your right hand side $F$ has at most finitely many jump discontinuities. Try to work out a variant of Picard's theorem that works in this setting.

Comment: @Ian: Correct. But, the proof of Picard's theorem is taking an integral equation and using Banach fixed point theorem prove that it has a unique fixed point. Then this integral equation satisfies the differential equation using continuity of $F$. How do I use that it has "finite" no. of discontinuities. BTW, I forgot to tell that $h$ is jointly continuous and uniformly lipschitz in first component w.r.t the second.

Comment: @Ian: got it. It has to be understood in the Caratheodory sense.

Comment: Indeed Caratheodory sense is enough here.

Comment: You can post an answer to your question, if you got it now.

Comment: @Ian: there is a problem. I can't verify the third property i.e. integrability mentioned in the [*Caratheodory Existence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_existence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).